# Transferring wp_post revisions to a custom table and reverting them back on edit page load

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation, wordpress-capabilities

I am trying to shift post revisions to a custom table and when the edit page is loaded then I transfer back the posts of those specific post back to wp_posts table

but I am encountering a problem

all the posts are transferring back and forth but on the revisions page I can see the last revision but if I scroll to the previous revisions it shows a error

"Sorry, something went wrong. The requested comparison could not be loaded."

I tried to find the error in cosole, debug.log and even in php logs but it does not show any kind of error

As I have made sure that the ID's of the post revisions and the parent ID's are the same I expect that they should be properly managed from the revisions page

```
function is_table_exist($table_name) {
    global $wpdb;
    
    $sql = "SHOW TABLES LIKE '" . esc_sql($wpdb->prefix . $table_name) . "'";
    $table = $wpdb->get_var($sql);
    
    return $table == $wpdb->prefix . $table_name;
}

if (is_table_exist('posts_revisions')) {
    // Table exists
    echo "Table exists!";
    function has_post_revisions() {
        global $wpdb;

        $revision_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'revision'" );
    
        return $revision_count > 0;
    }
    if ( has_post_revisions() ) {
        echo 'There are revisions in the posts table.';
        function transfer_post_revisions_to_custom_table() {
            global $wpdb;
        
            // Get revisions from the posts table
            $revisions = $wpdb->get_results(
                "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'revision'"
            );
        
            if ($revisions) {
                foreach ($revisions as $revision) {
                    // Check if the revision already exists in the custom table
                    $existing_revision = $wpdb->get_row(
                        $wpdb->prepare(
                            "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts_revisions WHERE id = %d",
                            $revision->ID
                        )
                    );
        
                    // Insert the revision into the custom table if it doesn't already exist
                    if (!$existing_revision) {
                        $wpdb->insert(
                            $wpdb->prefix . 'posts_revisions',
                            array(
                                'id' => $revision->ID,
                                'post_author' => $revision->post_author,
                                'post_date' => $revision->post_date,
                                'post_date_gmt' => $revision->post_date_gmt,
                                'post_content' => $revision->post_content,
                                'post_title' => $revision->post_title,
                                'post_excerpt' => $revision->post_excerpt,
                                'post_status' => $revision->post_status,
                                'comment_status' => $revision->comment_status,
                                'ping_status' => $revision->ping_status,
                                'post_password' => $revision->post_password,
                                'post_name' => $revision->post_name,
                                'to_ping' => $revision->to_ping,
                                'pinged' => $revision->pinged,
                                'post_modified' => $revision->post_modified,
                                'post_modified_gmt' => $revision->post_modified_gmt,
                                'post_content_filtered' => $revision->post_content_filtered,
                                'post_parent' => $revision->post_parent,
                                'guid' => $revision->guid,
                                'menu_order' => $revision->menu_order,
                                'post_type' => $revision->post_type,
                                'post_mime_type' => $revision->post_mime_type,
                                'comment_count' => $revision->comment_count
                            )
                        );
                    }
                }
        
                // Delete revisions from the posts table
                $wpdb->query(
                    $wpdb->prepare(
                        "DELETE FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'revision'"
                    )
                );
            }
        }
        
        // Run the function
        // transfer_post_revisions_to_custom_table();
        
    } else {
        echo 'There are no revisions in the posts table.';
    }
    
    
} else {
    // Table does not exist
    echo "Table does not exist!";
    function create_posts_revisions_table() {
        global $wpdb;
        
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'posts_revisions';
        $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
            id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            post_author bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
            post_date datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
            post_date_gmt datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
            post_content longtext NOT NULL,
            post_title text NOT NULL,
            post_excerpt text NOT NULL,
            post_status varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'publish',
            comment_status varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'open',
            ping_status varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'open',
            post_password varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
            post_name varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
            to_ping text NOT NULL,
            pinged text NOT NULL,
            post_modified datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
            post_modified_gmt datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
            post_content_filtered longtext NOT NULL,
            post_parent bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
            guid varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
            menu_order int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
            post_type varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'post',
            post_mime_type varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
            comment_count bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',
            PRIMARY KEY  (id),
            KEY post_name (post_name(191)),
            KEY type_status_date (post_type,post_status,post_date,ID),
            KEY post_parent (post_parent),
            KEY post_author (post_author)
        ) $charset_collate;";
        
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        dbDelta( $sql );
    }
    
    // Hook to run the function when WordPress initializes
    add_action( 'init', 'create_posts_revisions_table' );
    
}



function is_admin_post_edit_page() {
    if ( isset($_GET['action']) ) {
        // Check if the current screen is the post edit screen
        if ($_GET['action'] == "edit" ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

if ( is_admin_post_edit_page() ) {
    // Do something if it's the post edit page
    echo "is edit page";
    $this_post_id = $_GET['post'];
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "posts_revisions";
    $revisionArray = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE post_parent = '$this_post_id'");
    // print_r($revisionArray);


    foreach ($revisionArray as $revision) {
        $wpdb->insert(
            $wpdb->posts,
            array(
                'ID' => $revision->id, // Use the ID from the revision as the post ID
                'post_author' => $revision->post_author,
                'post_date' => $revision->post_date,
                'post_date_gmt' => $revision->post_date_gmt,
                'post_content' => $revision->post_content,
                'post_title' => $revision->post_title,
                'post_excerpt' => $revision->post_excerpt,
                'post_status' => $revision->post_status,
                'comment_status' => $revision->comment_status,
                'ping_status' => $revision->ping_status,
                'post_password' => $revision->post_password,
                'post_name' => $revision->post_name,
                'to_ping' => $revision->to_ping,
                'pinged' => $revision->pinged,
                'post_modified' => $revision->post_modified,
                'post_modified_gmt' => $revision->post_modified_gmt,
                'post_content_filtered' => $revision->post_content_filtered,
                'post_parent' => $revision->post_parent,
                'guid' => $revision->guid,
                'menu_order' => $revision->menu_order,
                'post_type' => $revision->post_type,
                'post_mime_type' => $revision->post_mime_type,
                'comment_count' => $revision->comment_count
            )
        );
    }
} else {
    // Do something else if it's not the post edit page
    echo "is not edit page";

}
```